# Riesz space of functions from any set $X$ to $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces, order-theory, vector-lattices

We collect certain functions from $f:X\to\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathscr{T}$ so that it is a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$ under the usual function addition, scalar product. Now we define an partial order on it: $f\leq g$ iff for all points $x\in X, f(x)\leq f(x)$. This is compatible with the vector space structure. Now we claim merely  $\mathscr{T}$ as a Riesz space without giving exact formula of infimum or supremum. Can I show the formula is $f\wedge g=\min\{f,g\}$? The thing is if we just first collect functions but we might not be sure that I have collected $\min\{f,g\}$.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but it seems like possibly you're asking whether any vector space of functions from $X$ to $\Bbb R$ is a Riesz space, with the natural partial order. If that's the question the answer is no; for example the space of all polynomials is not a lattice.

Comment: If it is given that it is a lattice, can I prove $\min\{f,g\}:=(f+g-|f-g|)/2$ must be in? I know this must be in the largest functional set of all functions but not necessarily in a subspace even it is a lattice. Or concisely, is the infimum or supremum of a sublattice the same as that in the lattice?

Comment: If it's given that it's a lattice _with_ the natural partial order, then yes, $f\land g=\min(f,g)$ is just the definition.

Comment: But the definition of $f\wedge g$ is a $h\leq f,g$ an for any $k\leq f,g$ we have $k\leq h$. So it is uniquely given by the partial order does not need extra defintion, does it? But the thing is we are not sure whether $\min\{f,g\}$ are still in the partially ordered subset.

Comment: With the natural order on the reals, what does that definition give for $1\land 2$?

Comment: Lets say $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R}$ be the set of all maps which is a Riesz space and then we have $1\wedge(\chi_{[0,1])}(x+3))\in\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R}$, but now we take the set of all functions with compat support. Then $1$ fail to be in. If we look at the sub-partially ordered set, there might be some elements have been removed in general. In a word will a sub partially ordered set of a lattice be a sublattice of the lattice? (E.g. not every subset of a group is a subgroup)

Comment: Of course a subspace of a lattice need not be a lattice. That was the point to my first comment. Then you said you were _given_ that you had a lattice. Make up your mind...

Comment: A sublattice must have the same inf and sup as before. E.g.
$a>c$, $b>c$, $c>f$, $d>f$ is a lattice. $a\wedge b=c$. But if I remove $c$, then it is still a lattice, but $a\wedge b=f$ now.